# Extract monthly categorical (dummy) variables in pandas from a time series

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe (df) with dated data on a monthly time series (end of the month). It looks something like this:

```
Date          Data
2010-01-31    625000
2010-02-28    750000
...
2014-10-31    450000
2014-11-30    475000
```

I would like to check on seasonal monthly effects.

This is probably simple to do, but how can I go about extracting the month from Date to create categorical dummy variables for use in a regression?

I want it to look something like this:

```
Date        01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
2010-01-31  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2010-02-28  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
...
2014-10-31  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
2014-11-30  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

I tried using pd.DataFrame(df.index.month, index=df.index)... which gives me the month for each date. I believe I need to use pandas.core.reshape.get_dummies to then get the variables in a 0/1 matrix format. Can someone show me how? Thanks.

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df.index.month)` should do it. (Make sure to drop one of the columns so you don't have linear dependence if you have an intercept). You can concat the result of that to the original df.

Comment: Wow. Very simple. Thank you for pointing this out. I really appreciate it, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got April:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4, freq='MS')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4), index=dates, columns=['data'])

df.ix[dates.month==4]
```

The idea is to make the dates your index and then do boolean index selection on the dataframe.

```
>>> df
                data
2013-01-01  0.141205
2013-02-01  0.115361
2013-03-01 -0.309521
2013-04-01 -0.236317


>>> df.ix[dates.month==4]
                data
2013-04-01 -0.236317
```